# Is it possible to use python dict comprehension when updating values?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

```
counts = defaultdict(int)
for elem in sets:         #list of sets
    for _ in elem:        #each set contains elements that may be duplicates among the sets
        counts[_] += 1
```

Is there a way to use dict comprehension for code like this?

Comment: give sample input and output

Comment: Could you explain why you want to use a list-comp for this? The title of your post and the body of the post are somewhat contradictory. A list-comp results in a `list` - what you're doing is wanting a `dict` it seems...

Comment: IndentationError - is that your problem? [mre], [ask]

Comment: Generally you do not want to use a list comprehension to get "side-effects" - use them if you want a list in result. For anything else - use a loop - not side effects of creating a list that you do not want.

Comment: Beside the point, but the conventional use of `_` as a variable name is [for a throwaway](/q/5893163/4518341), so using it here is confusing.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @JonClements yes, in this particular excercise the counts were required to be stored in a dict. I probably meant dict comprehension, but mistyped :)  these concepts still sound similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use a list comprehension for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/4518341) (i.e. updating `counts`).

Instead, if you replace `defaultdict(int)` with `Counter`, you can write the solution in one line. (I assume your end goal is to make your code shorter/cleaner.)

```
sets = [
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2},
    {3},
    {3}]
# ---
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x for s in sets for x in s)
print(counts)  # -> Counter({3: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2})
```

- Note: Instead of the nested generator expression, you might prefer to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(sets)`.

Comment: Yes, the goal was indeed to see if this was something that could be accomplished in one line, as it looks like a fairly simple iteration process.  I was thinking that maybe the walrus operator or something else that I am unfamiliar with may work in cases like this.  Thanks for pointing out the Counter collection!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adamant at using list comprehension, you can do this way:

```
>>> counts = {1:4, 2:5, 3:8, 4:2, 5:9}
>>> sets = [{2,3}, {3,1}, {2}]
>>> [[counts.update({e: counts[e]+1}) for e in si] for si in sets]
[[None, None], [None, None], [None]]
>>> counts
{1: 5, 2: 7, 3: 10, 4: 2, 5: 9}
```

But yes, as others suggested, you can do it using Counter:

#1: use Counter to get new counts from sets

#2: merge both new & default counters

#3: get Counter back into your dictionary

With sample input:

```
>>> counts = {1:4, 2:5, 3:8, 4:2, 5:9}
>>> sets = [{2,3}, {3,1}, {2}]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> cntr_new = Counter(x for s in sets for x in s)
>>> cntr_new
Counter({2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1})
>>> cntr_orig = Counter(counts)
>>> cntr_final = cntr_orig + cntr_new
```

Final result:

```
>>> dict(cntr_final)
{1: 5, 2: 7, 3: 10, 4: 2, 5: 9}
```

Comment: That list `[[None, None], [None, None], [None]]` is pointless. That's why we say, [don't use a list comprehension for side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753614/4518341). Use a plain for-loop instead. And that'd be a perfectly valid answer! To quote from [answer], *'The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”.'*